# jquery mobile -- make ui-btn-active apply to active list item

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I have a popup list in jquery mobile, with two items you can click to select. I can't get jquery mobile to "remember" -- via `class='ui-btn-active'` -- which listview item has been selected. You click on a list item, but the `ui-btn-active` class doesn't get attached to it.

This is the jquery I'm using (which doesn't work):

```
$('a.switchview').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active ui-state-persist');
});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div data-role='page' data-add-back-btn='true'>
    <a href='#popupSwitchView' class='ui-state-persist ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-eye ui-btn-icon-notext ui-alt-icon  ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline' data-transition='slideup' data-rel='popup' data-inline='true'>Switch view</a>

    <div data-history='false' data-role='popup' id='popupSwitchView'>
<a href='#' data-rel='back' data-role='button' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right' data-theme='a'>Close</a>

        <ul data-role='listview' data-icon='delete'>
            <li data-role='list-divider' style='font-style: oblique;'>Select choice</li>
            <li><a href='javascript:;' data-role='button' data-transition='fade' data-mini='true' class=' switchview' id='choiceA' name='theView' value='choiceA'>Choice A</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href='javascript:;' data-role='button' data-transition='fade' data-mini='true' class='switchview' id='choiceB' name='theView' value='choiceB'>Choice B</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/spzgqdur/)

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Return false from the click event and remove active class from previous selection:

```
$('a.switchview').on('click', function () {
    $('a.switchview').removeClass('ui-btn-active ui-state-persist');
    $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active ui-state-persist');
    return false;
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/spzgqdur/1/)**

Comment: ah, nice! thanks -- works perfectly in a desktop browser. However, in mobile (blackberry, iPhone 6) the state doesn't persist when the popup is closed then reopened